# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the problem which makes no since because I do the right way but unfortunately gives me error 
"Uncought TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" below is sample code

```
var parametersData = {};
data.dateList.forEach((date, index) => {
  parametersData[date].push(date);
  parametersData['success'].push(data.report[date]['success']);
  parametersData['unsuccess'].push(data.report[date]['unsuccess']);
});
```

[image]
Anyone please help what is the issue?
Thanks

Comment: `parametersData` is an object. You can't `push()` in to an object, only arrays.

Comment: The `parametersData` is an empty object. You can't access the `date` key since it doesn't exist in that object. You need to assign it to an array first in some way, for you to be able to push to that specific key.

Comment: I tried `parametersData = {'date':[], 'success': [], 'unsuccess': []};` still same error

Answer (score 0):

`parametersData` is an object. You can't `push()` in to an object, only arrays.

However as `data.dateList` appears to be an array itself and you're using a `forEach()` to iterate through it your output will have to be an array too. As such you can use `map()` instead;

```
let parametersData = data.dateList.map(date => ({
  [date]: date,
  success: data.report[date].success,
  unsuccess: data.report[date].unsuccess
}));
```

```js
let data = {
  dateList: ['01/01/2020', '02/02/2020'],
  report: {
    '01/01/2020': {
      success: 's1',
      unsuccess: 'us1'
    },
    '02/02/2020': {
      success: 's2',
      unsuccess: 'us2'
    }
  }
}

let parametersData = data.dateList.map(date => ({
  [date]: date,
  success: data.report[date].success,
  unsuccess: data.report[date].unsuccess
}));

console.log(parametersData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parametersData = {
 success:[],
 unsuccess:[]
};
data.dateList.forEach((date, index) => {
 if( parametersData[date]){
   parametersData[date].push(date);
 }else{
     parametersData[date] = []
    parametersData[date].push(date);
 }

 parametersData['success'].push(data.report[date]['success']);
 parametersData['unsuccess'].push(data.report[date]['unsuccess']);
});
```

hey try this you did not initialize the array as it's not able to push the element in it is simply check if there is an array then push in it and if it was not there just initialize one and then push into it

Answer (score 0):

Since parametersData[date] is empty, push is failing on this.
You should first assign the value as array and then push. E.g.,

If (!Array.isArray(parametersData[date])
parametersData[date] = []

parametersData[date].push(date)

Answer (score 0):

push only works for javascript arrays. Instead do this..

```
var parametersData={}; //<<Its an Object 
data.dateList.forEach((date,index)=>{
parametersData[date]=date; //assigning values 
parametersData['success']=data.report[date]['success'];
parametersData['unsuccess']=data.report[date]['unsuccess'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolve my problem

```
var parametersData = {data:[], success: [], unsuccess:[]};
data.dateList.forEach((date, index) => {
   parametersData->date.push(date);
   parametersData->success.push(data.report[date]['success']);
   parametersData->unsuccess.push(data.report[date]['unsuccess']);
});
```

Thank you all